# setOnClickListener for creating same layout below each other

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I`m new in android programming, I created add_layout.xml and what I want is to add it in activity_main.xml below each other by onClick each time the button clicked.
here is the codes:
add_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/addRoot">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Hello World..."
    android:id="@+id/plainText"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@id/plainText"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.androidstudio.addlayout.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addAnother"
    android:text="Add another"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button add, addAnother;
RelativeLayout activity_main;
RelativeLayout add_layout;
TextView plainText;
boolean clickAgain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    addAnother = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAnother);
    plainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plainText);

    add_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addRoot);


    activity_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RelativeLayout newLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_layout, null);
            activity_main.addView(newLayout);

        }
    });

    addAnother.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //?????????????
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks for help...

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: @Amy each time I click add, the layout added on each other, not below.

Comment: I want them to below each other

Comment: use appendView instead.

Comment: Can you help me how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the RelativeLayout of Activity_Main.xml With LinearLayout with orientation vertical.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.app.androidstudio.addlayout.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addAnother"
    android:text="Add another"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button add, addAnother;
LinearLayout activity_main;
RelativeLayout add_layout;
TextView plainText;
boolean clickAgain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    addAnother = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAnother);
    plainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plainText);

    add_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addRoot);


    activity_main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RelativeLayout newLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_layout, null);
            activity_main.addView(newLayout);

        }
    });

    addAnother.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //?????????????
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change This

```
 activity_main.addView(newLayout);
```

To

```
 activity_main.appendView(newLayout);
```

And also change the Layout of activity_main from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` (Virticle)

Comment: it would be good if you accept the answer with the upvote for appreciation :)